# how do I make a tiled map base64

Tags: slick2d, tiled

Hello everyone I am making a game in Java using the Slick library. this is my first time doing it and I need some help. for the map I am using tiled. and whenever I try to call the tmx file I get this error :

Thu May 29 16:17:57 EDT 2014 ERROR:Unsupport tiled map type: base64,zlib (only gzip base64 supported)

So my best guess would be that it needs to be gzip base64. That makes no sense to me, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you add the actual code you are using?

Comment: You got the right answer the next day, you should mark it as such to thank its author and so that it's clear that this question as been answered.

Answer (score 3):

You need either to choose that option when you're [creating a map in tiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4GhN.png), or you can click, on the menu bar, Map >> Map Properties >> and [select the compression you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxwo6.png).